Cannot Add Debug Points After Upgrading to Android Studio?
I recently upgraded to Android Studio Koala and now I'm unable to add debug points. When I try to add a breakpoint, it appears in the Bookmarks tab but does not show up in the line where I set it. Has anyone else encountered this issue or have any solutions?


In the new version of Android Studio, they have removed the traditional debug pointer. Now, when you click to set a debug point, the entire line gets highlighted instead of showing the debug symbol. I prefer the older method. If anyone knows how to bring it back, it would be helpful.
